# when is the podcast going to return?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, podcast

Missing Joel mostly :-) but seriously is it ever coming back?

Comment: I am with you I miss the weekly podcast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The podcast returned on April 20, 2011. As of this update, 30 episodes of the Stack Exchange Podcast (cf. Stack Overflow Podcast) have been produced. They are available [here, through the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/).

*The original version of this answer was written before April 20 and has been removed. It's still available in the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/88039/revisions).*

Comment: downloaded it this morning